# How to split and keep all the values from a dataframe in new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, delimiter

I need to split the `Product and Quantity` column. The new column name is `Quantity`.

If you see the example below, some rows will begin with quantity information in [2] and others in [1]. Also, I cannot use [-] because in the below example, the second split on '-' will work, but 3rd and 4th row will be incorrect

```
Product and Quantity
ABC-BBC-Bottle- 1 - 30 mg
BBC-44-Capsule- 10 - 500mg
KKP-Bottle- 5 - 30 mg
R2B-Powder-500mg
```

I need help with below:

1. How can I split when the position of '-' is not always the same in all rows?
2. How do I store all the values either before or after [-]. I know I can use [-2] for after and [2] for before. But its not storing all the values after I split using [2] or before when I use [-2]?

Currently, it looks like the below.

```
df = source_df[['Product and Quantity']]
df['Quantity'] = df['Product and Quantity'].str.split('-').str[2]
```

The output looks like the below.

```
Quantity

Bottle
Capsule
5
500mg
```

I want it to look like the below.

```
Quantity

Bottle - 1 - 30 mg
Capsule - 10 - 500mg
Bottle - 5 - 30 mg
Powder - 500mg
```

Comment: You can split before "Bottle, Capsule and Powder". Otherwise, you need a regular expression.

Comment: It looks like you have to come from the end and stop one word after you find an integer or until you reach the first part in the split array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reliable method: use a regex!

```
regex = r'[^-]+-((?:[^-]+-){,2}[^-]+)$'
df['Quantity'] = df['Product and Quantity'].str.extract(regex)
```

Output:

```
         Product and Quantity             Quantity
0   ABC-BBC-Bottle- 1 - 30 mg    Bottle- 1 - 30 mg
1  BBC-44-Capsule- 10 - 500mg  Capsule- 10 - 500mg
2       KKP-Bottle- 5 - 30 mg    Bottle- 5 - 30 mg
3            R2B-Powder-500mg         Powder-500mg
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GDqRXb/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Quantity'] = df[0].str.replace(' ', '').str.findall('\w+-\d*-*\d*mg').str[0].str.replace('-', ' - ')
```

Output:

```
         Product and Quantity              Quantity
0   ABC-BBC-Bottle- 1 - 30 mg     Bottle - 1 - 30mg
1  BBC-44-Capsule- 10 - 500mg  Capsule - 10 - 500mg
2       KKP-Bottle- 5 - 30 mg     Bottle - 5 - 30mg
3            R2B-Powder-500mg        Powder - 500mg
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. This option did not work for me. I got 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'' error